# Batch to loop through all files with predefined list or set of extensions and ignore all other file types

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64, file-type

I have following windows-batch script to loop through all files in the current directory:

```
FOR %%F in (%CD%\*.*) DO (
    :: I am doing my process here
)
```

I know I can loop through a specific file type by using `*.ext`, but I need to loop through all the given below file types and ignore all other types, that also in single `FOR` loop only:

```
php
phtml
css
js
sql
xml
```

How can I achieve that by doing slightest modifications to my code as possible ?

I am not much of a batch-scripter, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using this command line in your batch file?

```
for %%I in (*.php *.phtml *.css *.js *.sql *.xml) do echo "%%I"
```

Or perhaps better depending on what you want to do:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *.php *.phtml *.css *.js *.sql *.xml 2^>nul') do echo "%%I"
```

The version with **DIR** works also for files with hidden attribute set and is better when files in current directory are renamed, moved or deleted, i.e. the current directory files list changes due to the commands in the body of **FOR** loop because of list of files processed by **FOR** does not change once **DIR** command is executed which is not the case on using first solution. The first solution can easily result in an unexpected behavior like double processing a file, skipping unexpected files or an endless running loop when files are renamed, moved, modified or deleted in current directory.

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and `dir /?` for help on those two commands which support both specifying multiple wildcard patterns on arguments list.

Comment: Note: Using `for /f` and the text file as argument you can create the string representing the file-types during runtime and do not need to hardcode them.